# What are the effects of using `Script=foo' parameter in fontspec?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

What settings get added when `Script=foo` parameter is
passed to font commands with `fontspec`? Are those settings
related to fonts or related to LaTeX only? Are there any
adverse effects of loading the same settings globally?
Suppose my font contains 4 scripts namely abc, lmn, pqr,
xyz. To print the characters of xyz 'properly' I have
to call `Script=xyz` explicitly. (E.g., see: example no. 19,
p. 35, [`fontspec`](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontspec.pdf/0#section.4.3) manual, v2.8a 2022/01/15).

The explanation given there looks pretty explanatory about
how to use this feature, but the question here is, in our
hypothetical example, will adding the feature globally have
any adverse effect on the printing of characters from
scripts abc, pqr & lmn?

If the answer to this is yes, then technically it won't be a
great idea to have `\setmainfont[Script=foo]{myfont}` globally
since it affects the rendering of scripts other than foo,
right?

If the answer to this is no (as in if other scripts are
unaffected), then why do we even need a special setting? Why
can't we (in general) have all the settings that are
imported when we explicitly say `Script=foo` in our code?
Are those settings imported by LaTeX or it is a requirement
of fonts?

Comment: setting Script affect which rules are used to shape the font and a wrong (or missing) setting can mean that you get wrong output. See https://simoncozens.github.io/fonts-and-layout/features.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the reference, but I don't have much of font's knowledge to understand it fully. I would appreciate if you could tell me whether loading `Script=foo` affects the rendering of characters from scripts other than foo?

Comment: it depends on the font, but yes it could: If you set Script=Greek it will quite probably change the way arabic characters are processed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, thanks a lot, I will keep that in mind.